# zopim chatting service like div required

Tags: jquery, css

If you look at this site http://blog.zopim.com/, you will see on the bottom right side a chatting service. I actually don't want the chatting service. I just want the div to be up on the top of all the stuff present on my site, like this one is.

How can I accomplish this? If anyone has any samples please share, it would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Bryan told you, use position: fixed. There are a few particularities you have to know about the position fixed. You have to give you element a position relative to the browser window (use top, right, bottom or left). If you have other divs that are already in position fixed, you maybe gonna use the z-index. Check this:

html:

```
<div id="floating">hurra i amm floating</div>
```

css:

```
div#floating {
   position: fixed;
   bottom:0;
   right:0; 
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: pink;
}
```